# View compiler invocations for dotnet build of F# project (fsproj)

Tags: .net-core, f#, msbuild

Suppose I have a .NET Core (3.1 or 5.0) solution (`.sln`) that contains a few F# projects (`.fsproj`). I can build it with `dotnet build`.

However, I would like to know what invocations of the compiler (FSC) will be invoked for each project.

Is there are way to preview the compiler invocations of the `dotnet build` process?

---

Note this is not the same as a verbose build, because that shows the compiler invocations that *were* actually done, rather than the invocations that *should* be done. As a last resort `dotnet clean && dotnet build -v diag` does contain the information, but not in a convenient format.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to get this information is to use `dotnet build -bl` to generate a binary log and then use the [Structured Log Viewer](https://msbuildlog.com) to nativate to the `CoreCompile` target and `Fsc` task and press space on the log message that is displayed there.

[image: Structured Log Viewer showing the fsc invocation]